# Bitbucket doesn't save the vendor files

Tags: php, git, symfony, bitbucket, composer-php

I've cloned a repository in my localhost that is working right in a VPS.

```
$ sudo git clone https://msalsas@bitbucket.org/msalsas/itransformer-2.0.git
```

But when I try to clear cache with:

```
$ sudo php app/console cache:clear
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 42
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 42
```

I have the repository at bitbucket.org. 
This is what I can see at kriswallsmith's vendor directory form bitbucket repository:

[image: assetic → 0e18168c45df [0e18168c45df]]

Why cannot see the files and folders inside? It also happens in all vendor directories. And vendor directories in my localhost are empty.

I've tried to do:

```
$ sudo php composer.phar self-update
$ sudo php composer.phar update kriswallsmith/assetic
```

and I get the next error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                             
 - Removing twig/twig (v1.13.1)
 - Installing twig/twig (v1.13.2)
Loading from cache

 - Updating kriswallsmith/assetic 1.1.x-dev (0e18168 => 1d671c5)



[RuntimeException]                                                           
The .git directory is missing from /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/v  
endor/kriswallsmith/assetic, see http://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for mor  
e information                                                              



update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

Obvious, because there are no folders or files inside *vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic*.

If I type:

```
$ sudo php composer.phar install
```

I get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
- Removing twig/twig (v1.13.2)
- Installing twig/twig (v1.13.1)
Downloading: 100%         

Generating autoload files
PHP Warning:  require(/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 43
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/manolo/MiServer/itransformer-2.0/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 43
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



[RuntimeException]                                     
An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

Comment: First composer.phar install

Comment: Edited with "composer.phar install" output.

Comment: remove all content from vendor before. vendor should never be comitted to git.

Comment: This way works fine, but I have changed a part of a vendor bundle and that's why I'm not ignoring the vendor directory. I know it's not the better way, but I don't understand why bitbucket doesn't save these files.

Comment: If you have to change a bundles code, fork it and load the code from your fork! http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: Great! Easy way. Thanks

Comment: @Pazi - please make your answer so that i can mark it as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fault was the committed vendor directory. Especcially if a vendor is retrieved via git a whole git clone of the vendor is performed. Then if you commit your changes, all get added except already added files from another git repo.

Simple: Never commit vendor to a VCS. You have composer and with a committed composer.lock everyone will get exactly the same version.

And if you have to change a bundles code, fork it and [load the code from your fork!](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository). And later if the change affects the bundle in general, create a pull request to the original ;)

Comment: *If you have to change a bundles code, fork it and load the code from your fork!*. Could you add it to your answer? This is what has helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat the answer from the comments:

problem was, he committed the vendor directory to his git.

solution: Never ever put your vendor directory into your VCS